# XSLT Stylesheet (possibly) contains a recursion?

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

When viewing the XML file (congress.xml) in my browser I get the error...

```
Error during XSLT transformation: XSLT Stylesheet (possibly) contains a recursion.
```

The error is coming from the XSLT stlyesheet, which I have listed. The problem seems to be a result of line 89.

```
<xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="100 * round($candidatePercent)"/>
```

If I comment this out, the XML file congress.xml will at least display partially, but including it causes the browser to send back the error. If I am not mistaken, the drawCells template is trying to do a recursion. When attempting to view the congress.xml file, the browser just keeps trying to load the page, so I am assuming it is stuck in an endless loop maybe? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Open congress.xml in a browser. Open elections.xsl in a text editor and locate line 89.

The files are...

```
congress.xml
election.xsl
candidates.xml
vwstyles.css
vwlogo.png
```

Here is a google drive link to the all the files...
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9o30hEqwvyDc2Y3MktHNDQydnc&usp=sharing

If you think you can see where the error is coming from by looking at the code for the stylesheet, here it is...

elections.xsl - file where error is located.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="html"
      doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" />


    <xsl:variable name="candidateInfo" select="document('candidates.xml')/candidates/candidate[@candidateID]" />


   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</title>
            <link href="vwstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         </head>

         <body>
            <div id="wrap">
               <header>
                  <img src="vwlogo.png" alt="Voter Web" />
               </header>

               <h1>Minnesota Congressional Election Results</h1>

               <section id="votingResults">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="congressResults/district" />
               </section>

             </div>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="district">
      <h2>District <xsl:value-of select="@dNumber" /></h2>
      <table class="electionTable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Candidate</th>
               <th>Votes</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="candidates/candidate" />
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="candidate">
      <tr>

        <xsl:variable name="candidateVotes" select="sum(votes)" />
        <xsl:variable name="totalVotes" select="..//votes" />
        <xsl:variable name="candidatePercent" select="($candidateVotes) div ($totalVotes)" />
        <xsl:variable name="candidateName" select="$candidateInfo[@candidateID=current()/@candidateID]/name" />
        <xsl:variable name="candidateParty" select="$candidateInfo[@candidateID=current()/@candidateID]/party" />

        <th>            
            <xsl:value-of select="$candidateName" />
            (<xsl:value-of select="$candidateParty" />)         
        </th>

        <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($candidateVotes, '###,##0')" />
            (<xsl:value-of select="format-number($candidatePercent, '#0.0%')" />)
        </th>

        <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="drawCells">
                <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="100 * round($candidatePercent)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="party" select="$candidateParty" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>



      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="drawCells">
      <xsl:param name="cellCount" />
      <xsl:param name="party" />
      <xsl:if test="$cellCount > 0">
         <td class="{$party}"></td>
         <xsl:call-template name="drawCells">
            <xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="$cellCount - 1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="party" select="$party" />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your definition of `totalVotes` is incorrect.

```
 <xsl:variable name="totalVotes" select="..//votes" />
```

This will actually select all `votes` elements, but when you use it to calculate `candidatePercent` it will end up using the first `votes` element, resulting in your `candidatePercent` being a large number, and not a number between 0 and 1. (For the first candidate, it will be 193211 / 263 = 764.64). And you later multiple `candidatePercent` by 100 to make it even larger.

Try changing it to this instead

```
<xsl:variable name="totalVotes" select="sum(..//votes)" />
```

Also, I think you could do with changing the setting of `cellCount` as so

```
<xsl:with-param name="cellCount" select="round(100 * $candidatePercent)"/>
```

Comment: Ok, well that helped it at least display and not give the error, however, the drawCell template isn't drawing the bar graph as it should...

Comment: The question asked was really about why your template seemed to get stuck in a loop, so the issue with the bar graph probably warrants a new question. Having said that you could first try simply outputting the value of `cellCount` in the `drawCells` template, to make sure the numbers look OK.

Comment: From the look of your `drawCells` template, you are outputing a table cell for every `percent`, but that will give you `td` elements nesed within other `td` elements. Using an HTML table to output a bar graph is probably not the best approach though. Maybe it would be easier to simply output a `div` tag, with a width based on the percentage, and a back-ground colour to make it stand out. That would do away with the need for a recursive template at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim C. I am actually not allowed to touch the template. Somehow I need to make it work without altering that. I have been stuck on this for several days.